# jCrop setSelect Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am starting to play with jCrop and something that has me completely lost is using the `setSelect` part of the options. In this particular scenario, I have the following setup:

```
jcrop_reference.setOptions({
    onChange: update,
    onSelect: update,
    //aspectRatio: keepRatio ? originalRatio : null,
    bgColor: 'black',
    bgOpacity: 0.6,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    minSize: [250, 250],
    setSelect: [0, 0, 250, 250]
});
```

When I don't have the `setSelect` part entered, everything works fine but when I do I consistently receive

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

as the error on this method. I have tried it with numerous x/y coordinates, even taking some I had pulled off making a manual selection (meaning the coordinates are guaranteed accurate) and every time I get this error. The individual values make no difference at all.

Comment: I've setup a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCe2h/) with your given parameters and it seems to work just fine (in Chrome/Firefox). What browser are you using?

Comment: That's odd - yours even works with the image I have that was failing before. I'm going to try playing with it again and see if I can figure out the difference. Thanks!